# python dominate: build several tables concurrently

Tags: python, dominate

I am trying to use python3 and dominate 2.8.0 to build a webpage which contains two sections (top/bottom). While processing my input data, entries are to be added to each table depending on some criterion (lets call them valid and invalid)

I am not finding a way to selectively add rows to either table as I go, so that at the end
i can just

doc.render()

to get the whole structure output

I tried first building the main doc:

```
import dominate
from dominate import tags as tags
...

doc = dominate.document(title="MYDOC")
with doc:`
   tags.style("body{font-family:Helvetica}")
   tags.style("h1{font-size:x-large}")
   tags.style("h2{font-size:large}")
   tags.style("table{border-collapse:collapse}")
   tags.style("th{font-size:small;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px;background-color:#DDD}")
   tags.style("td{font-size:small;text-align:center;border:1px solid gray;padding:4px}")

   tags.h1("Test Page")
   tags.p(f"{starttime.strftime('%F %T')} Processing input file '{args.infile}'")
```

followed by a definition of two DIVs:

```
   tags.div(id="invalid_users")
   tags.hr()
   tags.div(id="valid_users")
   tags.hr()
```

and then defining the table headers:

```
  with tags.div(id="valid"):
      tags.h2(f"Valid for info only")
      with tags.table():
         with tags.thead():
            tags.th("id")
            tags.th("name")
            tags.th("verdict")
         tags.tbody(id="valid_table")

   with tags.div(id="invalid"):
      tags.h2(f"Invalid - to be handled")
      with tags.table():
         with tags.thead():
            tags.th("id")
            tags.th("name")
            tags.th("verdict")
         tags.tbody(id="invalid_table")
```

Then i wanted to process all entries in the file (read using json_load), adding them the appropriate table based on the ' verdict'

```
for entry in entry:
   if entry['verdict'] != INVALID:
      with tags.tbody(id="valid_table"):
         with tags.tr():
            tags.td(entry['id'])
            tags.td(entry['name'])
            tags.td(entry['verdict'])
   else:
      with tags.tbody(id="invalid_table"):
         with tags.tr():
            with.tags.td():
               tags.a(f"{entry['id']}", href=f"<A HREF=\"https://server/entry/{entry['id']}/edit")
            tags.td(entry['name'])
            tags.td(entry['verdict'])
```

and ultimately print the whole doc with

```
print(str(doc.render())
```

However, the entries are all printed as simple text (with the anchors where given) outside and below the second table

I had hoped that the first
`tags.div(id="invalid")`
and
`tags.div(id="valid")`
would define the DIV and similarly the
`tags.tbody(id="invalid_table")`
and
`tags.tbody(id="valid_table")`

defined those elements, so that I could later use these again like so

```
with tags.tbody(id="valid_table"):
     with tags.tr():
         ...
```

with these entries then added to the already defined tbodies with the same `id`

However, it seems that this not the way to define and later reference such elements.

How can this be done?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that kind of queueing.  You'll need to run two loops: one inside `with ... valid_table` and one inside `with ... invalid_table`.